# SQL how to find the average users from each category on a typical date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table as below;

```
Column Name       Column Datatype    Column Description
user_id           varchar            Unique user id
reg_ts            timestamp          Registration date
reg_device        varchar            Device registered   
reg_attribution   varchar            Acquisition type
```

I am trying to find "On a typical day, what share of registrants are coming from each acquisition
source?"

I wrote the code below but not sure how to divide by the total number of records:

```
select reg_ts as registiration_date,
reg_attribution as acquisition_type, 
count(*)
from users
group by 1,2
order by 1 asc
```

After I run the code above, I get only get the count of each acquisition type for each date. But I need to find the share of registrants are coming from each acquisition type. Can you please help me fix my query?

Comment: Provide a fiddle (or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) instead of verbal description. And show desired result for provided source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery that gets the count for a day (assuming that `reg_ts` is a day despite being a `timestamp`).

```
SELECT u1.reg_ts AS registiration_date,
       u1.reg_attribution AS acquisition_type,
       count(*) / (SELECT count(*)
                          FROM users u2
                          WHERE u2.reg_ts = u1.reg_ts) AS share
       FROM users u1
       GROUP BY u1.reg_ts,
                u1.reg_attribution
       ORDER BY u1.reg_ts ASC;
```

---

Edit:

If you want the ratio in regard to the total number of users rather than users that registered that day just remove the `WHERE` clause from the subquery.

```
SELECT u1.reg_ts AS registiration_date,
       u1.reg_attribution AS acquisition_type,
       count(*) / (SELECT count(*)
                          FROM users u2) AS share
       FROM users u1
       GROUP BY u1.reg_ts,
                u1.reg_attribution
       ORDER BY u1.reg_ts ASC;
```

Comment: The sum of the computed column should be one. Let's say you have 10 records in the table, and I want to calculate this:
day 1    acquisition type-1   2 users  --> 2/10
day 1    acquisition type-2   4 users  --> 4/10
day 2    acquisition type-1   2 users  --> 2/10
day 2    acquisition type-2   2 users  --> 2/10

Meaning instead of the counts 2,4,2,2, I should get 2/10, 4/10, 2/10, 2/10.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Eren: There isn't much to explain actually. The subquery just gets the count of all rows in the table. What in particular don't you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select reg_ts as registiration_date,
       reg_attribution as acquisition_type, 
        count(*) / sum(count(*))  over () as ratio
from users
group by 1, 2
order by 1 asc;
```

These have been available in MySQL version 8.0.